# Variance matrix for model errors

Tags: r, mixed-model, variance, error

I am having trouble with understanding how can I write out the variance matrix for model residuals. I have a very simple data with 6 observations:

> ```
> child  weight     age   
>   1     4000       0  
>   1     8000       12
>   1     11000      24
>   2     3500       0
>   2     10000      12
>   2     15000      24
> ```

I made a mixed model on this data: $weight_{i}=a + b \cdot age + \gamma_{i} + \tau_{i} \cdot age + \epsilon$ or it can be written also $Y=X \cdot \beta + Z \cdot \Gamma + \epsilon$.

I have found X and Z:

> ```
>        1   0              1  0  0   0
>        1   12             1  0  12  0
> X =    1   24         Z = 1  0  24  0
>        1   0              0  1  0   0
>        1   12             0  1  0   12
>        1   24             0  1  0   24
> ```

But now I need to find $D\epsilon$.

With R I found that $\sigma^{2}_{Intercept}=200.25519^2 \ and \ \sigma^2_{age}=92.02067^2, \ Corr=-0.979, \ \sigma^2_{residual}=368.09446, \ a=3958.333, \ b=385.417 $

But now I want to have the same results without Rs help and therefore I need to understand how to compute $D\epsilon$.

Thank you in advance for your help!